# MultiOTP with freeradius wrong

Tags: debian, freeradius, otp

I running freeradius 3.* on my server with The MultiOTP Version is 4.3.1.1 and for configuring FreeRADIUS I have used this guide:
http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/multiOTP-HOWTO 
and when I use radiusd `-X` the worng is just like this

[image]

whith my policy.conf

```
root@debian:~# cat /usr/local/etc/raddb/policy.d/policy.conf
policy {
    # Change to a specific prefix if you want to deal with normal PAP authentication as well as OTP
    # e.g. "multiotp_prefix = 'otp:'"
    multiotp_prefix = ''
    multiotp.authorize {
       # This test is for decimal OTP code only, otherwise you will have to change it
       # Try for example this simple test: if (!control:Auth-Type) {
        if (control:Auth-Type == 'MS-CHAP') {
              update control {
                      Auth-Type := multiotpmschap
              }
        }
        elsif (!control:Auth-Type && User-Password =~ /^${policy.multiotp_prefix}([0-9]{10})$/) {
            update control {
                Auth-Type := multiotp
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I find more any documents and wiki but it don't work. So I want konw what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 if (control:Auth-Type == 'MS-CHAP') {
```

to

```
 if (control:Auth-Type == MS-CHAP) {
```

Comment: despite the HOWTO explicitly having the quotes?

Comment: In your screen is marked that there is an problem, i think HOWTO is for older version of freeradius, where it works.

Comment: thank it work but the other miss like this  
`/usr/local/etc/raddb/policy.d/policy.conf[13]: Reference "${policy.multiotp_prefix}" not found
/usr/local/etc/raddb/policy.d/policy.conf[13]: Parse error expanding ${...} in condition
Errors reading or parsing /usr/local/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf
`
so waht can  it do work and how can i find the newest wiki to use and i want it to use for window AD.

Comment: Did you create modules for multiotp and multiotpmschap as in wiki [link](https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/multiOTP-HOWTO#freeradius-3-x-x)? Whitch version of freeradius you have?

Comment: i have freeradius 3 and i already create modules for multiotp and multiotpmschap in  mod-sites-available and sites-enabled.

Comment: maybe change `${policy.multiotp_prefix}` to `${multiotp_prefix}` or `${policy:multiotp_prefix}`... but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you but i try but it's  till no work .so i try other  open source like this privacyidea .and now i succeed work otp with it . so i think the MultiOTP is less wiki.